# Is the adjective "crucial" really informal?

Tags: word-usage, informal-language, style

I was looking for [synonyms for "necessary" in Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/indispensable), and to my surprise, I saw that they mark the adjective "crucial" as informal. Is this really accurate? It's not marked as informal in any other dictionary that I've checked, so I'm wondering if this is just a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Crucial has a formal meaning of "Essential or decisive for determining the outcome or future of something" (wiktionary).

It is somewhat informal to use "crucial" to mean "important". In formal English you should avoid hyperbole.

It is the sense of "crucial" that means "important" that is informal.  If you use it to mean "decisive" it is not informal.

The use of "crucial" to mean "important" was typical of Multicultural London English (MLE) at the end of the twentieth century.

Formal English means using the right word for the right meaning and avoiding figures of speech.

Comment: Hm, I find it a bit hard to distinguish the two meanings... but I'd say "necessary" is somewhat closer in meaning to "essential" than to "important" (even though I'd say they are all synonyms, no?), and it was as a synonym of "necessary" that Collins listed "crucial" as informal, so I still don't quite get it...

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts are right and this is bizarre, at least in American English. I can't imagine any high school student saying "yeah, man, it's crucial that I do my homework before class"

"Crucial" is more common in more formal contexts — books, business, etc. For example:

> In order to succeed as a business, it's crucial [*= very important*] that we consider our operating costs.

Comment: Crucial is (was) used in *exactly* this way in MLE and related vernaculars.  For example, in the '80s, Lenny Henry played a character who was a pirate radio broadcaster for "Crucial FM" (and used MLE in the role).  His production company is called "Crucial Enterprises"

Comment: @JamesK - so is MLE formal or informal?

Comment: Your big clue, for 'archetypal/comedic' MLE is that 'crucial' is often preceded by 'well'. "Man, this tune is banging, it's well crucial." ;)